# problems with emacs color themes, set-fontset and font-lock

Tags: emacs, fonts, themes

I use the following to ensure that lambda symbols etc are displayed using a specific font

```
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :family "PragmataPro")
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :height 130)
;; over-ride "fontset-defult" for all unicode characters
(set-fontset-font "fontset-default" 'unicode "PragmataPro")
```

And use a pretty lambda font-lock when working in scheme,

```
(defun pretty-lambdas ()
(font-lock-add-keywords nil
    '(("(\\(lambda\\)\\>" (0 (prog1 ()
                               (compose-region (match-beginning 1)
                                               (match-end 1)
                                               ?λ)))))))
```

this works fine when using the default emacs theme, but if i change theme `M-x load-theme:`  - the `λ` becomes some kind of "eastern" symbol, even though the character glyph for λ is provided by the face.

Any ideas? Is the load theme over-riding something?

-- EDIT --

I though the problem has solved itself, with the regular face it is now fine, but it still happens with italics.

Comment: It looks like load-theme is for custom themes.  Are you loading your own theme by any chance and have you tried narrowing it down to a specific line of code in your custom theme file?  I have my theme inside my init.el -- there aren't that many entries.  Do you have an encoding setting in your init to help control that possible issue (e.g., UTF-8)?

Comment: @lawlist I have added an answer as the problem has for some reason stopped being one.